# Hiding a button if table is not empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to  hide a "add to table" button once ONE (basically, if the table is not empty) input has been added to the table.

I tried using a IF statement but with no luck.

Since i am a begginer in this and need to do this for my homework, i would be very grateful, if you could atleast point me into the right direction.

Regards.

This is my code. I have a script that toggles a contact form trough a button click. I would like that button to dissapear if the table IS NOT empty. So 1 input = button gone. I am only addint the relavant part of the code.

EDIT: FINAL CODE.

```
   <?php
  $koncnica=".png";

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pass", "DB");
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT debelina, odkat, rob, vtor, id, narocilo  FROM polica where id='$id'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . 
    $row["debelina"] ." cm".'<a href="urediNarocilo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&uredi=debelina&narocilo='. $row['narocilo'] . '&value='.$row['debelina'].'"> &#9998;</a>'. "</td><td>" .
    $row["odkat"].'<a href="urediNarocilo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&uredi=odkat&narocilo='. $row['narocilo']  . '&value='.$row['odkat'].'"> &#9998;</a>'. "</td><td>" .
    $row["rob"].' <img src ="http://granital.owjej.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/' . $row['rob'] . $koncnica.'"height="20px"/><a href="uredizunanjo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&uredi=rob&narocilo='. $row['narocilo']  . '&value='.$row['rob'].'">&#9998;</a>'.
    "</td></tr>";}
echo "</table>";
} 
$conn->close();
?>

</table>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').click(function() {
      $('.b').toggle("slide");
    });
});
</script>

<?php if ($result->num_rows == 0) { ?>
  <div id="a">Dodaj</div>
<?php } ?>  
<?php
$conn->close();
?>   
<div class="b" style="display: none;">  
<div class="container">
 FORM 
</div>
</div>
```

This does the trick :)

```
<?php if ($result->num_rows == 0) { ?>
  <div id="a">Dodaj</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: phpmyadmin tag?

Comment: Hello. We'd like to help you, but we can't fix code that we can't see, and also we'll need a clearer description of what is going on than "no luck"...that's not an error message, or a description of unexpected behaviour in the application. Also it's unclear if the problem is in your user interface, your PHP, or your SQL. We can't help you without some better details. Thanks.

Comment: To be able to ___point you in the right direction___ we need to know ___where you currently are___ :) So please show us ALL the relevant code you already have

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. So it looks like your code currently will only show some HTML if `$row["TEST"]` is "empty". We don't know if that HTML contains your button or not? And we don't know what the content of `$row["TEST"]` is when you run the code. Don't forget we cannot see the contents of your screen, or your disk...or your mind. Think about what information we might need to know in order to be able to work out what your code is doing, and then provide it. Thanks.

Comment: for what you says, you are probably pointing to the wrong programming language. You probably looks for a client side language like js and not a server side like php. Once the page has loaded there is nothing you can do with php to alter the page

Comment: `if(empty($row["TEST"])){ echo 'the button html'; }`

Comment: Sorry, i made a bit of a mess. 

I have a table in which the user can store global settingsm which are editable but can only be inserted once. So what i want to do is hide a button to add a value once the value vas inserted. I will attach the code to the original post.

Comment: I don't see any update to your post yet...

Comment: @ADyson Here, i was in school, sorry :/ I updated the code so u can see what i want to achieve.

Comment: so where is the all-important button, in that code? I can't see what it is we're supposed to be hiding

Comment: This works as a sort of a "button". This div should be hidden. It opens up the form
<div id="a">Dodaj</div>
@ADyson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the "button" HTML in some PHP which will cause it only to be rendered if the table has no items in it:

```
<?php if ($result->num_rows == 0) { ?>
  <div id="a">Dodaj</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No problem. Hope you now understand how to use PHP to control the layout of your page! P.S. Please remember to mark the answer "accepted" if it helped you, thanks.